# Converting a dictionary of lists to a pandas.DataFrame using predefined headers

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have a dictionary that looks like the following:

```
date_pair_dict = {

    "15-02-2022 15-02-2022": ["key 1 val 1", "key 1 val 2", "key 1 val 3"],
    "15-02-2022 16-02-2022": ["key 2 val 1", "key 2 val 2", "key 2 val 3"],
    "16-02-2022 16-02-2022": ["key 3 val 1", "key 3 val 2", "key 3 val 3"],
    "16-02-2022 17-02-2022": ["key 4 val 1", "key 4 val 2", "key 4 val 3"]

}
```

And a list of headers:

```
headers = ["date pair header", "header val 1", "header val 2", "header val 3"]
```

I would like to create a `pandas.DataFrame` and write this to Excel, where the format would be the following **expected output**:

| date pair header | header val 1 | header val 2 | header val 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15-02-2022 15-02-2022 | key 1 val 1 | key 1 val 2 | key 1 val 3 |
| 15-02-2022 16-02-2022 | key 2 val 1 | key 2 val 2 | key 2 val 3 |
| 16-02-2022 16-02-2022 | key 3 val 1 | key 3 val 2 | key 3 val 3 |
| 16-02-2022 17-02-2022 | key 4 val 1 | key 4 val 2 | key 4 val 3 |

Right now, I'm using this (arguably very sad) method:

```
import pandas

date_pair_dict = {

    "15-02-2022 15-02-2022": ["key 1 val 1", "key 1 val 2", "key 1 val 3"],
    "15-02-2022 16-02-2022": ["key 2 val 1", "key 2 val 2", "key 2 val 3"],
    "16-02-2022 16-02-2022": ["key 3 val 1", "key 3 val 2", "key 3 val 3"],
    "16-02-2022 17-02-2022": ["key 4 val 1", "key 4 val 2", "key 4 val 3"]

}

headers = ["date pair header", "header val 1", "header val 2", "header val 3"]

list_of_keys, list_of_val_1, list_of_val_2, list_of_val_3 = [], [], [], []

for key in date_pair_dict.keys():

    list_of_keys.append(key)

    val_1, val_2, val_3 = date_pair_dict.get(key)

    list_of_val_1.append(val_1)
    list_of_val_2.append(val_2)
    list_of_val_3.append(val_3)

dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(
    {
        headers[0]: list_of_keys,
        headers[1]: list_of_val_1,
        headers[2]: list_of_val_2,
        headers[3]: list_of_val_3,
    }
)
```

Which is not scalable whatsoever. In reality, this `date_pair_dict` can have any number of keys, each corresponding to a list of any length. The length of these lists will however always remain the same, and will be known beforehand (I will always predefine the `headers` list).

Additionally, I believe this runs the risk of me having a dataframe that does not share the same order as the original keys, due to me doing the following:

```
for key in dictionary.keys():

    ....
```

The keys are date pairs, and *need to remain in order* when used as the first column of the dataframe.

**Is there a better way to do this, preferably using a dictionary comprehension?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you said you can use a comprehension on your dict key/value pairs:

```
import pandas as pd

date_pair_dict = {

    "15-02-2022 15-02-2022": ["key 1 val 1", "key 1 val 2", "key 1 val 3"],
    "15-02-2022 16-02-2022": ["key 2 val 1", "key 2 val 2", "key 2 val 3"],
    "16-02-2022 16-02-2022": ["key 3 val 1", "key 3 val 2", "key 3 val 3"],
    "16-02-2022 17-02-2022": ["key 4 val 1", "key 4 val 2", "key 4 val 3"]

}

headers = ["date pair header", "header val 1", "header val 2", "header val 3"]

df = pd.DataFrame([[k] + v for k,v in date_pair_dict.items()], columns=headers)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        date pair header header val 1 header val 2 header val 3
0  15-02-2022 15-02-2022  key 1 val 1  key 1 val 2  key 1 val 3
1  15-02-2022 16-02-2022  key 2 val 1  key 2 val 2  key 2 val 3
2  16-02-2022 16-02-2022  key 3 val 1  key 3 val 2  key 3 val 3
3  16-02-2022 17-02-2022  key 4 val 1  key 4 val 2  key 4 val 3
```

Comment: I don't use dictionaries often, will using `.items()` in this way maintain the order of the keys and their values (as defined in my `date_pair_dict`) when converting it to a dataframe?

Comment: Depends on the version of Python that is used. You should always reorder the resulting dataframe explicitly.

Comment: Understood, thank you for the helping hand. Maintaining the order of the keys is a secondary problem in any case, and should likely be dealt with as such. I wasn't at all aware that different versions of Python treated dicts differently.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can simply do:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(date_pair_dict, orient='index').reset_index()
df.columns = headers
```

It's always a good idea to exploit existing methods before trying to come up with your own constructor.

Comment: I really like this method due to it being concise and easy to follow. I've accepted the answer by @Tranbi due to my question asking for a comprehension, but I will definitely be comparing both this and the accepted answer further. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to create a list of rows from the input dictionary, after which it is straightforward:

```
import pandas as pd

date_pair_dict = {

    "15-02-2022 15-02-2022": ["key 1 val 1", "key 1 val 2", "key 1 val 3"],
    "15-02-2022 16-02-2022": ["key 2 val 1", "key 2 val 2", "key 2 val 3"],
    "16-02-2022 16-02-2022": ["key 3 val 1", "key 3 val 2", "key 3 val 3"],
    "16-02-2022 17-02-2022": ["key 4 val 1", "key 4 val 2", "key 4 val 3"]

}
headers = ["date pair header", "header val 1", "header val 2", "header val 3"]

date_pairs = [[k] + v for k, v in date_pair_dict.items()]
 df = pd.DataFrame(date_pairs)
df.columns = headers
print(df)
#         date pair header header val 1 header val 2 header val 3
# 0  15-02-2022 15-02-2022  key 1 val 1  key 1 val 2  key 1 val 3
# 1  15-02-2022 16-02-2022  key 2 val 1  key 2 val 2  key 2 val 3
# 2  16-02-2022 16-02-2022  key 3 val 1  key 3 val 2  key 3 val 3
# 3  16-02-2022 17-02-2022  key 4 val 1  key 4 val 2  key 4 val 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Some fancy `rename` approach:

```
>>> pandas.DataFrame([[key,*values] for key,values in date_pair_dict.items()]).rename(columns=headers.__getitem__))

        date pair header header val 1 header val 2 header val 3
0  15-02-2022 15-02-2022  key 1 val 1  key 1 val 2  key 1 val 3
1  15-02-2022 16-02-2022  key 2 val 1  key 2 val 2  key 2 val 3
2  16-02-2022 16-02-2022  key 3 val 1  key 3 val 2  key 3 val 3
3  16-02-2022 17-02-2022  key 4 val 1  key 4 val 2  key 4 val 3
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use list traversal to construct the output dictionary:

```
import pandas

date_pair_dict = {

    "15-02-2022 15-02-2022": ["key 1 val 1", "key 1 val 2", "key 1 val 3"],
    "15-02-2022 16-02-2022": ["key 2 val 1", "key 2 val 2", "key 2 val 3"],
    "16-02-2022 16-02-2022": ["key 3 val 1", "key 3 val 2", "key 3 val 3"],
    "16-02-2022 17-02-2022": ["key 4 val 1", "key 4 val 2", "key 4 val 3"]

}

headers = ["date pair header", "header val 1", "header val 2", "header val 3"]

e = [[k] + v for k,v in date_pair_dict.items()]
d = {}
for i in range(len(e[0])):
    d[headers[i]] = [a[i] for a in e]
    
d = pandas.DataFrame(d)
```